# Establishing a Neo4j.rb database on a RDBMS tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, relationships

I'm new to both Rails and Neo4j.  I've been trying to use Neo4j.rb whilst following the Team Treehouse tutorials on building simple Ruby applications.  I realise there are a number of differences in syntax between the two data model sets, but can't seem to get this working.  I've looked around at a variety of Neo4j.rb resources but can't seem to work out where the problem is.  It seems as though it's in the html.erb files, but I can't be sure it's not the graph itself as the neo4j-admin gem doesn't work with my version of jruby.

Below are the examples of my model files, my users are named Knockers (long story!) and I am using the devise-neo4j gem created by cfitz.  If you notice any significant inefficiencies then please let me know too (there are bound to be loads!):

```
class Knocker < Neo4j::Rails::Model

 attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :knocker_id
 property :first_name, :type => String
 property :last_name, :type => String
 property :facebook_token, :type => String, :index => :exact
 property :created_at, :type => Time
 property :updated_at, :type => Time

 has_n(:statuses).from(Status, :created_by).relationship(Created_By)

 property :email, :type => String, :null => false, :default => "", :index => :exact
 property :encrypted_password, :type =>  NilClass
 property :knocker_id, :type => Fixnum 
 index :knocker_id

 property :remember_created_at, :type => Time
 index :remember_token, :type => :exact

 property :reset_password_token,   :type => NilClass, :index => :exact
 property :reset_password_sent_at, :type =>   Time

 property :sign_in_count, :type => Fixnum, :default => 0
 property :current_sign_in_at, :type => Time
 property :last_sign_in_at, :type => Time
 property :current_sign_in_ip, :type =>  String
 property :last_sign_in_ip, :type => String

 # property :confirmation_token, :type => NilClass, :index => :exact
 # property :confirmed_at, :type => DateTime
 # property :confirmation_sent_at, :type => DateTime

 ## Lockable
 #  property :failed_attempts, :type => Fixnum, :default => 0
 # property :locked_at, :type => DateTime
 #  property :unlock_token, :type => String, :index => :exact

 ## Token authenticatable
 # property :authentication_token, :type => String, :null => true, :index => :exact

 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
 # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
      :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 def full_name
   first_name + " " + last_name
 end
end

class Status < Neo4j::Rails::Model
 attr_accessible :content, :knocker_id
 property :content, :type => String
 property :knocker_id, :type => Fixnum

 property :created_at, :type => Time, :value => Time.now
 has_one(:created_by).to(Knocker).relationship(Created_By)

 validates :content, presence: true,
                  length: { minimum: 2 }

 validates :knocker_id, presence: true

end

class Created_By < Neo4j::Rails::Relationship
 property :created_at
 def to_key
   persisted? ? [id] : nil
 end

# this is for the routing helpers
 def to_param
  persisted? ? neo_id.to_s : nil
 end
end
```

The following is the statuses view show.html.erb file:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @status.incoming(Knocker.created_by) %>
  <% end %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Content:</b>
  <%= @status.content %>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_status_path(@status) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', statuses_path %>
```

And the following is the StatusesController:

```
class StatusesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_knocker!, only: [:new]

  # GET /statuses
  # GET /statuses.json
  def index
    @statuses = Status.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @statuses }
    end
  end

  # GET /statuses/1
  # GET /statuses/1.json
  def show
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @status }
    end
  end

  # GET /statuses/new
  # GET /statuses/new.json
  def new
    @status = Status.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @status }
    end
  end

  # GET /statuses/1/edit
  def edit
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /statuses
  # POST /statuses.json
  def create
    @knocker = Knocker.find(params[:knocker_id])
    @status = Status.new(params[:status])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.save
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @status, status: :created, location: @status }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /statuses/1
  # PUT /statuses/1.json
  def update
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.update_attributes(params[:status])
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /statuses/1
  # DELETE /statuses/1.json
  def destroy
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])
    @status.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to statuses_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

As mentioned, I've tried numerous different approaches (and this may well be a mashup of methods because of that!).  Initially I just added the has_one and has_n attributes to the models, but on reading the Neo4j.rb documentation, tried to base it around the Actor, Movie, Role layout... seems not to have worked!  The server doesn't show the user/Knocker's name on the show.html.erb page and currently brings up an error of:

```
undefined method `created_by' for Knocker:Class
```

The problem is clearly because I've been following a tutorial based on a RDBMS.  If anyone has any useful tips on methods to easily convert RDBMS applications to Neo4j.rb then that would be handy!

Apologies for the stupid problem, I'm clearly missing something very straight forward!

The complete files so far can be found at https://github.com/davemate23/knock4

Answer (score 0):

From which view does this error come from ?

I see that in the `statuses.html.erb` you return an Enumerable of nodes instead of a property, `@status.incoming(Knocker.created_by)`  Try to declare a relationship with has_one on the Status class so that you can write `@status.created_by.name`

Alternative try `@status.node(:outgoing, Knocker.statuses).name` using the core api (see https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j%3A%3ACore-Nodes-Properties-Relationships)

Btw, this should have been done in the controller or model layer.

Another possible error is that you have added the wrong nodes to the relationship. There are no validations when you create relationships. Eg. `some_user.status << User.create()` will not complain, but you will probably get errors when you unexpected find a user object while traversing the status relationship.

Comment: This is the Statuses view with the show.html.erb file.  I originally started with the has_n and has_one declarations on the models and including an @status.knocker.name but this didn't work, so from following one of the guides on your Github page ended up changing it all to this.  If I add the has_n and has_one relationship declarations to a model, will this automatically create a relationship, if so how does it determine which nodes of that class it should be related to?  Also are there any changes to the controller made when creating this sort of relationship?

Comment: When changing the show.html.erb file to @status.created_by.first_name it now brings up the error "undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass".  This is the same error I got using the method mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: Yes, if you declare `has_n(:status).to(Status)` then you can create new relationship using `a_knocker.status.create(some_properties_for_status)`

Comment: I've uploaded it to Github at the following address https://github.com/davemate23/knock4, still not quite sure what you're getting at and what should be written where!